# как добавить на куб разные текстуры

Tags: android, opengl

Здравствуйте.  Я хочу нарисовать куб в openGL, у которого на каждой грани - своя текстура.

Вот такой вот рабочий пример куба у которого одна текстура используется для обтягивания всех его граней:

```
public class Cube extends Abstract3DFigure {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;
    private int[] textures = new int[6];

    private float vertices[] = {
            //Vertices according to faces
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //Vertex 0
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //v3

            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    //...
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    };


    private float texture[] = {
            //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
    };


    private byte indices[] = {
            //Faces definition
            0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2,            //Face front
            4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 6,            //Face rightButtonPositiion
            8, 9, 11, 8, 11, 10,         //...
            12, 13, 15, 12, 15, 14,
            16, 17, 19, 16, 19, 18,
            20, 21, 23, 20, 23, 22,
    };


    public Cube(Context context) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }


    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);   //Move 5 units into the screen
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        //Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        //Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        //Enable the vertex and texture state
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        //Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.border);
        //Generate one texture pointer...
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        //...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        //Clean upButtonPositiion
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    private Bitmap loadResurse(Context context, int resourceId) {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            //Always clear and close
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            is = null;
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Мне бы хотелось использовать для разных граней - разные текстуры. В данном коде я гружу только одну текстуру. `Bitmap bitmap = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.border)`;
А нужно 6 текстур, я могу их получить таким образом, но как потом их натянуть на разные грани мне не понятно.

```
Bitmap east = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.east);
        Bitmap north = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.north);
        Bitmap west = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.west);
        Bitmap south = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.south);
        Bitmap up = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.up);
        Bitmap down = loadResurse(context, R.drawable.down);
```

Как я могу это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Как вариант вместе с массивом позиций и текстурных координат можно передавать еще один атрибут - это флаг типа float, какую текстуру использовать. Затем проверять значение флага в шейдере: например, если flag==0 - использовать первую текстуру, если flag==1, то вторую, и т.д.